# is it possible to call overridden method from parent struct in Golang?

Tags: oop, inheritance, go, overriding

I want to implement such code, where B inherit from A and only override A's Foo() method, and I hope the code to print B.Foo(), but it still print A.Foo(), it seems that the receiver in Golang can't work like this in C++, in which when dynamic binding is enabled, the code can work like what I want.

I also post another piece of code, which works, but it's too hard to implement, and more like a hack way, I think it's not a Golang style.

So my problem is: if the parent's Bar() method has some logic, for example, open a file, then read some lines, and use Foo() to output these lines to `stdout`, and the Child (in the example is B) wants to use most of them, the only difference is that the Child wants Foo() to output the lines to another file. How should I implement it? I have heard that Golang's inheritance can't work like C++ or Java, and what's right way in Golang?

```
package main 

import ( 
        "fmt" 
) 

type A struct { 
} 

func (a *A) Foo() { 
        fmt.Println("A.Foo()") 
} 

func (a *A) Bar() { 
        a.Foo() 
} 

type B struct { 
        A 
} 

func (b *B) Foo() { 
        fmt.Println("B.Foo()") 
} 

func main() { 
        b := B{A: A{}} 
        b.Bar() 
}

output: A.Foo()
```

the following piece works, but when write

```
a := A{}
a.Bar()
```

you will encounter a compiler error

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type I interface {
    Foo()
}

type A struct {
    i I

}

func (a *A) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("A.Foo()")
}

func (a *A) Bar() {
    a.i.Foo()

}

type B struct {
    A
}

func (b *B) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("B.Foo()")
}

func main() {
    b := B{A: A{}}
    b.i = &b     // here i works like an attribute of b
    b.Bar()

output: B.Foo()
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861786/golang-struct-calling-embedded-type-methods-when-method-has-been-overloaded

Answer (score 34):

As you wrote, what Go has is not really inheritance, the method that allows inheritance like features is called Embedding.

http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding

What it means basically is that the embedded struct has no idea that it is embedded, so you cannot override anything that is called from it.  You can actually take the embedded struct and take a reference for it only from the embedding struct.

So your best way to do it is more or less like your second example - through some sort of dependency injection using interfaces. i.e - A has a reference to some interface that does the actual work, say `worker`, that writes to a file or whatever. Then when instantiating B, you also replace A's `worker` with another worker (you can do it even without embedding A of course). The A just does something like `myWorker.Work()` without caring what worker it is.

Comment: in fact, the second example uses composition to achieve, both A and B composite an interface I, this is what golang encounrages.

Comment: yeah, as I wrote your second example is the way to go. I'd just change it so the parent struct is not its own interface.

Comment: Not_a_Golfer, what do you mean by "parent struct is not its own interface" - how would it look in code, what you're suggesting? :-)

Comment: I'm interested as well, this answer solved a problem I was having overriding a method in an embedded struct, curious about what the proper code looks like.

Comment: @neurosnap hell, I wrote this almost 2 years ago, I have no idea what I meant :)

Comment: Hah. My problem is those interfaced methods use struct properties so I need to embed the interface. Is that considered bad practice? My issue is how do I have an interface separate from the structure without a lot of redundant function params?

Comment: I tried to explain the differences and have a section on how you can kind of achieve method overriding here: http://hackthology.com/object-oriented-inheritance-in-go.html

Answer (score 18):

Been struggling with this myself. Found 2 solutions:

1. **Idiomatic Go way**: implement the common "method" as external function with interface as argument.

   ```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    // Fooer has to Foo
    type Fooer interface {
        Foo()
    }

    // Bar is a proxy, that calls Foo of specific instance.
    func Bar(a Fooer) {
        a.Foo()
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // usage

    func main() {
        b := &B{} // note it is a pointer
        // also there's no need to specify values for default-initialized fields.
        Bar(b) // prints: B.Foo()
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // implementation

    // A is a "base class"        
    type A struct {
    }

    func (a *A) Foo() {
        fmt.Println("A.Foo()")
    }

    // B overrides methods of A
    type B struct {
        A
    }

    func (b *B) Foo() {
        fmt.Println("B.Foo()")
    }
   ```

Try it on Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/2TbmHUs9_Dt

2. Similar to your second option: **interface hackery**. However, since Bar() is not specific to A (it is common to A and B), let's move it to base class, and hide implementation details and all dangerous stuff:

   ```
    package main

    import "fmt"

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Usage

    func main() {
        b := NewB()
        b.Bar() // prints: B.Foo()

        a := NewA()
        a.Bar() // prints: A.Foo()
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Implementation.

    // aBase is common "ancestor" for A and B.
    type aBase struct {
        ABCD // embed the interface. As it is just a pointer, it has to be initialized!
    }

    // Bar is common to A and B.
    func (a *aBase) Bar() {
        a.Foo() // aBase has no method Foo defined, so it calls Foo method of embedded interface.
    }

    // a class, not exported
    type a struct {
        aBase
    }

    func (a *a) Foo() {
        fmt.Println("A.Foo()")
    }

    // b class, not exported
    type b struct {
        aBase
    }

    func (b *b) Foo() {
        fmt.Println("B.Foo()")
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Now, public functions and methods.

    // ABCD describes all exported methods of A and B.
    type ABCD interface {
        Foo()
        Bar()
    }

    // NewA returns new struct a
    func NewA() ABCD {
        a := &a{}
        a.ABCD = a
        return a
    }

    // NewB returns new struct b
    func NewB() ABCD {
        b := &b{}
        b.ABCD = b
        return b
    }
   ```

Try it on Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/0Zcs_arturP

Comment: Very interesting, thanks, but I don't see any actual call of the child method on a variable with the parent type

Comment: Modifying his example, one can access the embedded parent member through its name and call the method from there e.g.
```
 func (b *B) Foo() {
     fmt.Println("B.Foo()")
     parent := b.A
     parent.Foo() // prints "A.Foo()"
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

Recently I have a need to do this and the composition method proposed by OP works great.

I try to create another example to try to demonstrate the parent and child relationship and make it easier to read.

https://play.golang.org/p/9EmWhpyjHf:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type FruitType interface {
    Wash() FruitType
    Eat() string
}

type Fruit struct {
    name  string
    dirty bool
    fruit FruitType
}

func (f *Fruit) Wash() FruitType {
    f.dirty = false
    if f.fruit != nil {
        return f.fruit
    }
    return f
}
func (f *Fruit) Eat() string {
    if f.dirty {
        return fmt.Sprintf("The %s is dirty, wash it first!", f.name)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s is so delicious!", f.name)
}

type Orange struct {
    *Fruit
}

func NewOrange() *Orange {
    ft := &Orange{&Fruit{"Orange", true, nil}}
    ft.fruit = ft
    return ft
}
func NewApple() *Fruit {
    ft := &Fruit{"apple", true, nil}
    return ft
}

func (o *Orange) Eat() string {
    return "The orange is so sour!"
}

func main() {
    log.Println(NewApple().Eat())
    log.Println(NewApple().Wash().Eat())
    log.Println(NewOrange().Eat())
    log.Println(NewOrange().Wash().Eat())
}
```

Comment: Really easier to follow than everything else +1

Answer (score 6):

Go does not support virtual method overriding. The design pattern you want to use is thus not directly supported by Go. It is considered bad practice because changing the implementation of A.Bar() would break all derived classes like B that assume A.Foo() will be called by A.Bar(). The design pattern you want to use will make your code brittle.

The way to do it in Go would be to define a Fooer interface with a Foo() method. A Fooer would be passed as argument to Bar() or stored in a field of A and called by A.Bar(). To change the Foo action, change the Fooer value. This is called composition, and it is much better than changing Foo action by inheritance and method overriding.

Here is an idiomatic way to do what you want to do in Go: https://play.golang.org/p/jJqXqmNUEHn. In this implementation, the Fooer is a member field of A that is initialized by a parameter of to the instance factory function `NewA()`. This design pattern is preferable when the Fooer doesn't change frequently during the lifetime of A. Otherwise, you may pass the Fooer as parameter of the `Bar()` method.

This is how we change the behavior of `Foo()` in Go. It is called composition because you change the behavior of `Bar()` by changing the instances composing A.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Fooer interface {
    Foo()
}

type A struct {
    f Fooer
}

func (a *A) Bar() {
    a.f.Foo()
}

func NewA(f Fooer) *A {
    return &A{f: f}
}

type B struct {
}

func (b *B) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("B.Foo()")
}

type C struct {
}

func (c *C) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("C.Foo()")
}

func main() {
    a := NewA(new(B))
    a.Bar()

    a.f = &C{}
    a.Bar()
}
```

PS: Here is a possible implementation of the design pattern you wanted to implement for documentation purpose: https://play.golang.org/p/HugjIbYbout

Answer (score 4):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


//-- polymorphism in work

// children specification by methods signatures
// you should define overridable methods here
type AChildInterface interface {
    Foo()
}

type A struct {
    child AChildInterface
}

//-- /polymorphism in work


// hard A.Bar method
func (a *A) Bar() {
    a.child.Foo() // Foo() will be overwritten = implemented in a specified child
}


//-- default implementations of changeable methods

type ADefaults struct{}

func (ad ADefaults) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("A.Foo()")
}

//-- /default


//-- specified child

type B struct {
    ADefaults // implement default A methods from ADefaults, not necessary in this example
}

// overwrite specified method
func (b B) Foo() {
    fmt.Println("B.Foo()")
}

//-- /specified child

func main() {
    a := A{ADefaults{}}
    a.Bar()

    // Golang-style inheritance = embedding child
    b := A{B{}} // note: we created __Parent__ with specified __Child__ to change behavior
    b.Bar()
}
```

Output:

```
A.Foo()
B.Foo()
```

Answer (score 4):

Coming from C++/Python, where OOP is much better represented, and discovering go (now everything is web or web related, right?!) I too stumbled upon this issue. I feel that OOP in go is only half-baked. With embedding (struct's anonymous fields), methods of the inner type come along for free, inducing the idea of inheritance, only to learn later on the limitations. However, playing a bit with embedded interfaces within structs and with a bit of discipline, C++-like constructors, inheritance, polymorphism, and methods override can be emulated.

Considering the example - https://play.golang.org/p/nqt0haPYt2x

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math"
    "unsafe"
)

//Emulate C++ like polymorphism in go, through template method design pattern

//========================== Shape interface ==============================
//like C++ abstract classes
type Shape interface {
    Area() float32      //Shape's area
    Perimeter() float32 //Shape's perimeter
    Name() string       //Shape's name (like rectangle, circle, square etc.)
}

//====================== PrintableShapeInfo =============================
type PrintableShapeInfo struct {
    Shape             //like C++ inheritance, although go has no such a thing
    preetyPrintPrefix string
}

//Init a new PrintableShapeInfo object. The method is distinct so that it can be called from other contexts as well
//
//Remark: emulates the C++ constructor init part
func (printableShapeInfo *PrintableShapeInfo) Init(preetyPrintPrefix string) {
    printableShapeInfo.preetyPrintPrefix = preetyPrintPrefix
}

//The central method emulates the template method design pattern. It prints some info about a shape by dynamically calling (through pointers) the right methods
//
//Remark: the design patterns best practices recommend to favor composition over inheritance (i.e. model a ShapeInfoPrinter class, which takes a Shape interface and prints its info),
//for the sake of showcasting the template method pattern, the "go's inheritange" like model was chosen
func (printableShapeInfo *PrintableShapeInfo) PrintInfo() {
    log.Println("PrintableShapeInfo::PrintInfo")
    fmt.Printf("%s PrintableShapeInfo::PrintInfo - %s:\n",
        printableShapeInfo.preetyPrintPrefix, printableShapeInfo.Name()) //dynamically calls (through a pointer) a shape's Name method (like Rectangle.Name or Circle.Name or Square.Name)
    fmt.Printf("\tArea: %f\n", printableShapeInfo.Area())           //dynamically calls (through a pointer) a shape's Area method (like Rectangle.Area or Circle.Area or Square.Area)
    fmt.Printf("\tPerimeter: %f\n", printableShapeInfo.Perimeter()) //dynamically calls (through a pointer) a shape's Perimeter method (like Rectangle.Perimeter or Circle.Perimeter or Square.Perimeter)
}

//====================== Rectangle =============================
type Rectangle struct {
    PrintableShapeInfo         //like C++ inheritence, although go has no such a thing
    width              float32 //rectangle's width
    height             float32 //rectangle's heigh
}

//Creates and init a new rectangle object and properly set its Shape's interface methods set (similar to C++ class' vtable)
//
//Remark: emulates the C++ constructor
func NewRectangle(width float32, height float32) *Rectangle {
    log.Println("NewRectangle")
    rectangle := new(Rectangle)   //allocate data
    rectangle.Shape = rectangle   //set the Shape's specific vtable with the Rectangle's methods. Critical for template method pattern
    rectangle.Init(width, height) //init class
    return rectangle
}

//Init a new rectangle object. The method is distinct so that it can be called from other contexts as well (such as a square Init method. See below)
//
//Remark: emulates the C++ constructor init part
func (rectangle *Rectangle) Init(width float32, height float32) {
    log.Println("Rectangle::Init")
    //call the base's PrintableShapeInfo struct Init method
    rectangle.PrintableShapeInfo.Init("###")
    rectangle.width = width
    rectangle.height = height
}

//Compute the rectangle's area
func (rectangle *Rectangle) Area() float32 {
    log.Println("Rectangle::Area")
    return float32(rectangle.width * rectangle.height)
}

//Compute the rectangle's perimeter
func (rectangle *Rectangle) Perimeter() float32 {
    log.Println("Rectangle::Perimeter")
    return float32(2 * (rectangle.width + rectangle.height))
}

//Get the rectangle's object name
func (rectangle *Rectangle) Name() string {
    log.Println("Rectangle::Name")
    return "rectangle"
}

//====================== Circle =============================
type Circle struct {
    PrintableShapeInfo         //like C++ inheritence, although go has no such a thing
    radius             float32 //circle's radius
}

//Creates and init a new circle object and properly set its Shape's interface methods set (similar to C++ class' vtable)
//
//Remark: emulates the C++ constructor
func NewCircle(radius float32) *Circle {
    log.Println("NewCircle")
    circle := new(Circle) //allocate data
    circle.Shape = circle //set the Shape's specific vtable with the Rectangle's methods. Critical for template method pattern
    circle.Init(radius)   //init class
    return circle
}

//Init a new circle object. The method is distinct so that it can be called from other contexts as well if needed
//
//Remark: emulates the C++ constructor init part
func (circle *Circle) Init(radius float32) {
    log.Println("Circle::Init")
    //call the base's PrintableShapeInfo struct Init method
    circle.PrintableShapeInfo.Init("ooo")
    circle.radius = radius
}

//Compute the circle's area
func (circle *Circle) Area() float32 {
    log.Println("Circle::Area")
    return math.Pi * float32(circle.radius*circle.radius)
}

//Compute the circle's perimeter
func (circle *Circle) Perimeter() float32 {
    log.Println("Circle::Perimeter")
    return 2 * math.Pi * float32(circle.radius)
}

//Get the circle's object name
func (circle *Circle) Name() string {
    log.Println("Circle::Name")
    return "circle"
}

//====================== Rectangle =============================
//Implement Square in terms of Rectangle
type Square struct {
    Rectangle //like C++ inheritance, although go has no such a thing
}

//Creates and init a new square object and properly set its Shape's interface methods set (similar to C++ class' vtable)
//
//Remark: emulates the C++ constructor init
func NewSquare(width float32) *Square {
    log.Println("NewSquare")
    square := new(Square) //allocate data
    square.Shape = square //set the Shape's specific vtable with the Rectangle's methods. Critical for template method pattern
    square.Init(width)    //init class
    return square
}

//Init a new square object. The method is distinct so that it can be called from other contexts as well if needed
//
//Remark: emulates the C++ constructor init part
func (square *Square) Init(width float32) {
    log.Println("Square::Init")
    //since the Rectangle field is anonymous it's nice that we can directly call its un-overwritten methods but we can still access it, as named Rectangle, along with its (even overwritten) methods
    square.Rectangle.Init(width, width) //call Rectangle's init to initialize its members. Since Square is implemented in Rectangle's terms, there nothing else needed
}

//Compute the square's area
func (square *Square) Area() float32 {
    log.Println("Square::Area")
    //since the Rectangle field is anonymous it's nice that we can directly call it's un-overwritten methods but we can still access it, as named Rectangle, along with it's (even overwritten) methods
    return square.Rectangle.Area()
}

//Compute the square's perimeter
func (square *Square) Perimeter() float32 {
    log.Println("Square::Perimeter")
    //since the Rectangle field is anonymous it's nice that we can directly call it's un-overwritten methods but we can still access it, as named Rectangle, along with it's (even overwritten) methods
    return square.Rectangle.Perimeter()
}

//Get the square's object name
func (square *Square) Name() string {
    log.Println("Square::Name")
    return "square"
}

func main() {
    //initialize log subsystem so that we can display them at the main's end
    // bufWriter := bytes.NewBuffer()
    logStringWriter := bytes.NewBufferString("")
    log.SetOutput(logStringWriter)

    rectangle := NewRectangle(2, 3) //create a Rectangle object
    rectangle.PrintInfo()           //should manifest polymorphism behavior by calling Rectangle's Area, Perimeter and Name methods

    circle := NewCircle(2) //create a Circle object
    circle.PrintInfo()     //should manifest polymorphism behavior by calling Circle's Area, Perimeter and Name methods

    square := NewSquare(3) //create a Square object
    square.PrintInfo()     //should manifest polymorphism behavior by calling Square's Area, Perimeter and Name methods

    //print constructs sizes
    fmt.Printf(`
Go constructs sizes:
    Shape interface size as seen by Rectangle struct:  %d
`, unsafe.Sizeof(rectangle.Shape))
    fmt.Printf("\tRectangle struct size: %d", unsafe.Sizeof(rectangle))

    fmt.Printf(`
    Shape interface size as seen by Circle struct:  %d
`, unsafe.Sizeof(circle.Shape))
    fmt.Printf("\tCircle struct size: %d", unsafe.Sizeof(circle))

    fmt.Printf(`
    Shape interface size as seen by Square struct:  %d
`, unsafe.Sizeof(square.Shape))
    fmt.Printf("\tCircle struct size: %d", unsafe.Sizeof(square))

    //print the logs
    fmt.Println("\n\nDumping traces")
    fmt.Print(logStringWriter)
    return
}
```

The central method (template method) is PrintInfo which, called for any defined shape, works as expected, by calling the right Area, Perimeter, and Name methods. Ex. circle.PrintInfo() will call circle.Area, circle.Perimeter and circle.Name.

The constructor functions, NewRectangle, NewCircle, and NewSquare construct shape objects and they're split into three steps:

- space allocation
- methods set (C++ like vtable) init, needed for polymorphic behavior
- struct members initialization, through Init methods

The struct member initialization is a distinct step for better code reuse. For example, Rectangle Init calls the base PrintableShapeInfo Init method while the Square Init method calls the base Rectangle Init (which calls PrintableShapeInfo Init, as said before).

Also, due to interfaces embedding, the object sizes increases only a bit, with a pair of pointers to the methods set and data area as can be seen in the example output.

I think the code looks pretty decent and the only concern being if specifically setting the Shape's interface method set (as the case of NewRectangle, NewCircle, and NewSquare functions) would trigger some side effects, as the code appears to work correctly?!

Comment: If this is the state of a "decent" C++ style code, no wonder why people are jumping ship to languages like Go and Rust. https://play.golang.org/p/klY36h890k3