# Method overriding in Go

Tags: pointers, go, overriding

According to the code below:

```
type A struct {
}

func (a *A) Func1(i int) {
    a.Func2(i)
}

func (a *A) Func2(i int) {
    fmt.Println(i)
}

type B struct {
    *A
}

func (b *B) Func2(i int) {
    i += 1
    b.A.Func2(i)
}

func main() {
    var b = B{}
    b.Func1(1)
}
```

I have a struct `A`, and 2 functions `Func1`, `Func2` in `A`, function `A.Func1` will call `A.Func2`.

And I have another struct `B` that embedding struct `A`, and have a function `Func2` that overriding `A.Func2`.

When I declare `b` that has value `B{}` and call `b.Func1(1)`, it will run `A.Func1` and call `A.Func2` but not run `A.Func1` and call `B.Func2` that I override `A.Func2` in `B`.

My question is how can I fix the code so that when I call `b.Func1(1)`, it will run `A.Func1` and call `B.Func2` that I override `A.Func2` in `B`.

Comment: There's no overriding in Go. `B.Func1` works thanks to [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding). `Func1` is "promoted" to `B`. However, it's still operating on type `A` so it has no way of calling `B.Func2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang Method Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123911/golang-method-override)

Comment: So the only way to fix this problem is copy `A.Func1` to `B.Func1` and change `a.Func2(i)` to `b.Func2(i)`?

Comment: Sure, that would work, but at that point you're implementing exactly the same things, it may be better to just make both A and B implement the same interface.

Comment: In my project, `A` in this code is `http.Client`, I want to use `B` to promote `http.Client.Do` and when I call `B.Get`, `B.Post` ... etc, they will finally call `B.Do` not `http.Client.Do`. I think implement them to a interface probably redundant. Or not at all?

Comment: In this case, it's not difficult to implement your own `Get`, `Post`, etc.. methods, those are fairly small and straightforward. So you can just have `B` hold (not embed) a `http.Client` and you implement your own `Do`, `Post`, etc... methods. Whether you use an interface or not depends on whether you want other bits of your code to use your class or a `http.Client` interchangeably.

Comment: Simply copy go source code to my project and edit a little bit like this?
https://play.golang.org/p/nLxiya7tM0x

Comment: Seems about right. I would name `http.Client` though rather than make it embedded. That way you won't have any nasty surprises if someone calls one of the `http.Client` methods not implemented by `B`.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling promoted method `a.Func2(i)` using `b` receiver `b.A.Func2(i)` type. So in actual it is calling the function with receiver `A`. Since there is no method overriding in go. Only there are embedded types . So you have to create your version of the same function if you wants your function to be used. Like

```
func (a *B) Func(i int){
    fmt.Println("Calling function from b receiver")
}
```

can call this in `B`'s `Func2`

```
func (b *B) Func2(i int) {
    i += 1
    b.Func(i)
}
```

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079775/type-composition-overriding-interface-types) for more details

Answer (score 3):

Using interface you can get a little bit closer the functionality you want.

```
type F2 interface {
    Func2(i int)
}

func Func1(f2 F2, i int) {
    f2.Func2(i)
}

type A struct {
}

func (a *A) Func2(i int) {
    fmt.Println(i)
}

type B struct {
    *A
}

func (b *B) Func2(i int) {
    i += 1
    b.A.Func2(i)
}

func main() {
    var a = &A{}
    Func1(a,1)

    var b = &B{}
    Func1(b,1)
}
```

Comment: This works. But if `A.Func1` is from other package, I still need to copy `A.Func1` to `Func1` and rewrite it.

Comment: If `A.Func1` is from another package lets say `package new`. Just call the function with package name after importing the package `new`. as `new.A.Func1`

Comment: I mean your `Func1` is not in A, but `Func1` from other package is in `A`. if I want use your answer, I still want to make `A.Func1(...)` to `Func1(A, ...)`.