# Using overridden parent method in other parent methods

Tags: go

I have two types, B and C, which share all methods, but implement one of them differently.  I would like to express this by having a parent type A, containing the implementations of the shared methods, and embedding A in B and C.  (Don't Repeat Yourself!) The snag is that the method that differs between B and C is called in many of the shared methods.  What's the idiomatic way to structure such code?

My current implementation looks essentially like this (https://play.golang.org/p/RAvH_hBFDN; based on an example by [Dave Cheney](http://dave.cheney.net/2016/08/20/solid-go-design)):

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Legger interface {
    Legs() int
}

type Cat struct {
    Name string
    L    Legger
}

// Cat has many methods like this, involving calling c.L.Legs()
func (c Cat) PrintLegs() {
    fmt.Printf("I have %d legs.\n", c.L.Legs())
}

// OctoCat is a Cat with a particular implementation of Legs
type OctoCat struct {
    Cat
}

func (c OctoCat) Legs() int {
    return 8
}

// TetraCat has a different implementation of Legs
type TetraCat struct {
    Cat
}

func (c TetraCat) Legs() int {
    return 4
}

func main() {
    c := TetraCat{Cat{"Steve",nil}}
    c.L = &c
    c.PrintLegs() // want 4
    o := OctoCat{Cat{"Bob",nil}}
    o.L = &o
    o.PrintLegs() // want 8
}
```

The type definitions themselves look nice and clean, but the initialization code in `main` is wacky (first the `nil` in the struct literal, then `c.L = &c`, what?).  Is there a better solution?

A similar pattern was presented in [is it possible to call overridden method from parent struct in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21251242/1224002), but the question of whether this is the idiomatic way to proceed was not answered.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches I would consider for solving this:

**1.** Refactor your code to have a single type `Cat` with the fields `Name string` and `Legs int`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Cat struct {
    Name string
    Legs int
}

func (c *Cat) PrintLegs() {
    fmt.Printf("I have %d legs.\n", c.Legs)
}

func main() {
    c := &Cat{"Steve", 4}
    c.PrintLegs() // want 4
    o := &Cat{"Bob", 8}
    o.PrintLegs() // want 8
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/_PNAu3sgG8

**2.** Do away with the `Cat` type and just have `TetraCat` and `OctoCat` implement the `Legger` interface:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Legger interface {
    Legs() int
}

func PrintLegs(l Legger) {
    fmt.Printf("I have %d legs.\n", l.Legs())
}

// OctoCat is a Cat with a particular implementation of Legs
type OctoCat struct {
    Name string
}

func (c *OctoCat) Legs() int {
    return 8
}

// TetraCat has a different implementation of Legs
type TetraCat struct {
    Name string
}

func (c *TetraCat) Legs() int {
    return 4
}

func main() {
    c := &TetraCat{"Steve"}
    PrintLegs(c) // want 4
    o := &OctoCat{"Bob"}
    PrintLegs(o) // want 8
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/m4QvKhSj0w