# Go embedded custom interfaces

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand Go's interfaces and embedding.

What I'm trying to do here is create my own custom `writer` and `reader`  where each one implements either `io.Writer` or `io.Reader`

Now I want to take these custom structures that implement basic interfaces and embed them into another custom struct that implements `Read/Write/Close`.  The below code is what I have so far but when I run it I get the following error

`cannot use test (type MyReadWriteCloser) as type io.Writer in argument to fmt.Fprintf:
    MyReadWriteCloser does not implement io.Writer (missing Write method)`

I thought when you embed a structure within another structure you also get the methods of the embedded structures.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"io"
)

type MyWriter struct {
    w io.Writer
}

func (m MyWriter) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    // encrypt b and write to underlying writer
    m.w.Write(b)
    return
}

type MyReader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (m MyReader) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    // decrypt b
    m.r.Read(b)
    return
}

type MyReadWriteCloser struct {
    MyWriter
    MyReader
}

func (m MyReadWriteCloser) Close() error {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main start")

    r, w := io.Pipe()

    test := MyReadWriteCloser{
        MyWriter{w},
        MyReader{r},
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(test, "hello world\n")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong so the interfaces/types are not actually being imbedded.

```
type MyWriter struct {
    w io.Writer
}
```

should be

```
type MyWriter struct {
    io.Writer
}
```

And based on my understanding a proper embed leaves you no reason to define a method like;

```
func (m MyWriter) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    m.w.Write(b)
    return
}
```

because the body would just be `m.Write(b)` so that just doesn't make sense. If you embed a type the embedding type will be able to call methods from the embedded type directly (it's the nearest thing to inheritance, it looks the same to a casual reader). I don't remember the resolution rules if there are conflicts between method or property names in embedded types or the embedding type an embedded type but a good rule of thumb would be to avoid embedding types that will cause naming conflicts because the behavior will not be obvious.

EDIT:
Example of how to override a method in the underlying type and invoke the 'base' (i quote cause some gophers might be offended by that word choice) method from inside it;

```
func (m MyWriter) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
     b = EncodeBFromMethodThatsInScopeHere(b)
     return m.Writer.Write(b)
}
```

Basically, if you want to explicitly use the embedded types method you can refer to it as a property of the type using the embedded types type as if it were a property name.

Comment: One thing that I would eventually like to do is write something to `MyReadWriteCloser` and have `MyWriter` encrypt whatever it is I'm writing.   The only way I can imagine this working is by writing my own `Write` method and calling `Write` on the underlying writer from within my custom `Write` method which is why I had `m.w.Write(b)`.  If I remove `w` from my struct then I have no way (at least I don't think I do) of writing to the underlying writer.  Hope that makes sense because I keep going in circles in my mind trying to figure this out.  Sorry if my terminology is wrong.

Comment: @Jeff I'll edit with an example doing that, the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861786/golang-struct-calling-embedded-type-methods-when-method-has-been-overloaded

Answer (score 2):

You're not embedding the interfaces, you're making them fields in your struct.

Embedding looks like:

```
type MyReader struct {
    io.Reader
}
```

If you want to manually delegate to the interface, you need to use the same method name

```
func (m MyReader) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return m.r.Read(b)
}
```